# Disable Trackpad Clicks on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad

I have a question similar to "[How do I disable the trackpage in ubuntu 10.04](https://superuser.com/questions/145316/how-do-i-disable-the-trackpad-in-ubuntu-10-04)" but I just want to disable trackpad clicks.

In my case this is not a laptop, but rather a [Dell Zino](http://www.dell.com/us/en/home/desktops/inspiron-zino-hd/pd.aspx?refid=inspiron-zino-hd&cs=19&s=dhs) running [Ubuntu NBR 10.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook) and my input device is [Rii mini](http://www.engadget.com/2010/03/05/rii-mini-wireless-keyboard-is-perfect-for-your-htpc-not-your-wi/) connected via some form of wireless to the USB wireless dongle. This device has a keyboard and a trackpad.

I have tried using some instructions I found ([Disable Synaptics Touchpad](http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/03/24/disable-synaptics-touchpad/) & [Disable tapping and scrolling on a Synaptics touchpad](http://g33kgrrl.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/disable-tapping-and-scrolling-on-a-synaptics-touchpad-6/)) from the other question, but I don't get the correct result.

I thought that this might do it, but it doesn't seem I am using synaptics drivers:
`htpc-livingroom:~$ synclient MaxTapTime=0
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

This is my xorg.conf file:

`Section "Screen"
        Identifier      "Default Screen"
        DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier      "Default Device"
        Driver  "fglrx"
EndSection`

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not have a Synaptics touchpad, you should not be mucking about with xorg.conf settings. Assuming that the Rii Mini is properly detected by Linux, you should be able to go to Mouse Preferences (in the "System" menu) and disable tap-to-click:

[image]

If the "Touchpad" tab does not appear, then Linux is not detecting the Rii Mini as having a touchpad. You could follow the [instructions to report a bug](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection#In%20case%20your%20touchpad%20features%20like%20scrolling,%20tapping,%20etc%20does%20not%20work%20at%20all.) in HAL or the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GPointingDeviceSettings](http://live.gnome.org/GPointingDeviceSettings) (a GUI program) already? Just `sudo apt-get install gpointing-device-settings` and you have it installed.

Answer (score 0):

you can disable tap-click for a small amount of time after keyboard activity by doing

```
syndaemon -d -t
```

see `man syndaemon` for more info

Comment: It doesn't seem I am using synaptics drivers